# How to change layout to on page instead of inside a tab in product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove the tabs layout on the Magento product detail page. I am currently using Mag 1.9 RWD theme. Instead of displaying the Specs, Description, The Collection, Reviews and Related Products in tabs I just want them be laid out on one page.

I have found the section in rwd\mytheme\layout\catalog.xml that creates the tabs but as a Magento newb I am unsure on best practices to remove these sections outside of the tabs and directly into the page.

```
 <block type="mmcatalog/product_view_tabs" name="product_tabs" as="product_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
                 <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Specifications</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description"
                       template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup">
                        <group>detailed_info</group>
                    </action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                        <value>Description</value>
                    </action>
                    <block type="magenmagic_attributeoptions/description" name="attribute.option.description" as="option.description" template="magenmagic/attributesoptions/description.phtml"/>
                </block>
                 <block type="mmcatalog/product_view_collections" name="product.collection" as="product.collection" template="catalog/product/view/collection.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>The Collection</value></action>
                </block>
                 <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related.new" as="related_products_new" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Related Products</value></action>
        </block>
            </block>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice in the correct method to approach this

Comment: I have the same question. I hope someone can help us!

Comment: which problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146262)